# Can you put/restrict a canvas to a layout

Tags: android, canvas, android-relativelayout

I'm quite new to Android programming and I'm stuck on how to get this right.

My situation is I want to draw a rectangle inside a RelatativeLayout and be able to change the shape of the rectangle dynamically relative to the size of the RelativeLayout which does not encompass the whole screen.

My problem is when I try to implement this, the size of the rectangle is still relative to the screen size

Is there a way where I can restrict the canvas size to the RelativeLayout size or is there a better way?

Here is part of my code from the maim activity

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    blueView = new Bar(this);
    blueView.setLayoutParams(rl);
    blueLayout.addView(blueView);
```

And I also have a Bar class that extends View

```
public class Bar extends View{

Rect theBar;

public Bar(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    theBar = new Rect();
    theBar.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);

    Paint blue = new Paint();
    blue.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    blue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawRect(theBar, blue);
}
```

}

Comment: try replacing `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()` with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: Seems to have worked, thank you so much